# displaying all tables with different schema with SQLalchemy's MetaData

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have some trouble displaying all table names from my database. Is there an option where I can skip the specification of the exact table schema?

```
    def display(self):
       m = MetaData()
       m.reflect(self.engine,schema = "schemaname")
       for table in m.tables.values():
           print(table.name)
```

This works fine for all the tables with the specific schema name but couldn't find any information for how to display all of them. When I don't mention the schema name in **.reflect()** no table names are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m.reflect` can get only one schema. if schema option is None, get public schema tables. if you want to get all schema table you need to schema list first.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect, MetaData

engine = create_engine('CONNECTION_STRING')

inspector = inspect(engine)

for schema in inspector.get_schema_names():
    for table in inspector.get_table_names(schema):
        print(table.name)
```

this schema list has `infomation_shcema`. if no need, you need to except this shcema infomation.